# How to make callback for mobile in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make callback for mobile in laravel. 
In current mobile version, when click signup, it goes to website and user signup. I am trying to make user back to app again after successful signup.
So I should make callback when click signup on site.How can I do this?

Comment: please share some code and explain a bit better as what you are trying to do ???

Comment: Can we meet on skype?